# Make negative spacing between letters and make them darker on the overlapping parts

Tags: spacing, titlesec, kerning

I want to make number of the chapter to be as big as the paper. This is what I have achieved so far.

[image]

What I want is to make negative spaces between letters, so they overlap and the overlapping part is darker than the numbers themselves. **Or** to make the second number darker than the first one, but still overlap. I have absolutely no idea how to automate that.

I also keep `titlesec` in my code, because I am not aware of anything that could go wrong (or right), when I implement the solution.

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,draft]{scrbook}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
paperwidth=11.7in,
paperheight=8.27in,
top=1in,
bottom=1in,
outer=1.5in, 
inner=0.7in,
voffset=0in,
marginparwidth=0.5in,
marginparsep=0.2in,
footskip=0em,
headsep=0pt,
nofoot,
nohead  
}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries\color{gray!100!white!50}\fontsize{\paperheight}{\paperheight}\selectfont}%
{\resizebox{!}{\paperheight+1in}{\thechapter}}%
{-\paperheight}%
{\color{black}\raggedright\Huge}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0in}{-1.5in}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{20}
\chapter{Twenty One}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I made several changes.  I made the color for each digit `\color{gray!100!white!\intens` where `\intens` is changed for each digit, from 50 to 75 and then (if needed) 100.

Also, I present the chapter, instead of `\thechapter`, as `\edef\tmp{\thechapter}\expandafter\squeeze\tmp\relax`, where `\squeeze` does a negative kern after each digit and a change of color.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,draft]{scrbook}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
paperwidth=11.7in,
paperheight=8.27in,
top=1in,
bottom=1in,
outer=1.5in, 
inner=0.7in,
voffset=0in,
marginparwidth=0.5in,
marginparsep=0.2in,
footskip=0em,
headsep=0pt,
nofoot,
nohead  
}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\chapterfont[LetterSpace=-12]{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\gdef\intens{50}\normalfont\bfseries\color{gray!100!white!\intens}\fontsize{\paperheight}{\paperheight}\selectfont}%
{\resizebox{!}{\paperheight+1in}{%
  \chapterfont\edef\tmp{\thechapter}\expandafter\squeeze\tmp\relax}}%
{-\paperheight}%
{\color{black}\raggedright\Huge}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0in}{-1.5in}{40pt}
\def\squeeze#1#2\relax{#1\ifx\relax#2\relax\ \else%
  \xdef\intens{\the\numexpr\intens+25\relax}%
  \kern-180pt\color{gray!100!white!\intens}\squeeze#2\relax\fi}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{20}
\chapter{Twenty One}

\lipsum[1]

\setcounter{chapter}{101}
\chapter{Century Plus Two}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks very good, but when I do `\newfontfamily\chapterfont[LetterSpace=-12]{Calibri}`, a strange vertical line appears on the right. Why does this happen?

Comment: @MichaelFraiman I do not know why it does that, however, I EDITED and fixed it by having `\squeeze` set an extra space to the big chapter number when complete.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes you you use tikz+opacity to get the overlaps colored?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I had to add even two spaces to fix that. Very strange behaviour.

Comment: @daleif I don't use `tikz`.  I just modified the code that the OP had presented, changing as little as was needed to get what seemed like the desired result.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes you should. Drawing each number using tikz with an opacity og 0.5 will color blend the overlaps automatically. One just have to do you sqeeze macro in a different manner.

Comment: @daleif I am not likely to figure it out on short notice.  However, I would welcome you to either provide a separate answer or to modify my answer.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I've added an example below, though have not integrated it with `titlesec` as I'm unfamiliar with that package.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I guess this may be a little off-topic, but how not to print the title of the chapter in the beginning?

Comment: @MichaelFraiman By "in the beginning", do you mean in a table of contents?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes no, I mean on the page where chapter starts, its title should not be printed.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman Typically, you would use `\chapter{}` instead of `\chapter{Twenty One}`.  If you still needed the name in the table of contents, but not on this page, you would say `\chapter[Twenty One]{}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes thx, this sounds OK.

Answer (score 6):

The negative kerning is quite easy to do with `fontspec` and XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. I've used the `LetterSpace` font feature for the font used for the number. Giving it a negative value decreases the inter-letter spacing.  I've given it a value of `-12` as an example, which doesn't actually overlap them but gives you an idea of what you can do. (I tried larger numbers but nothing looked very pleasing to my eye.) This is not a scale number but an "normalized additive factor defined as a percentage of the font size. For a 10 pt font 1.0 will add 0.1pt between each letter." (`fontspec` docs, p.33).

This doesn't solve the "darker when overlapping" issue, though.  For that you might need to treat the digits individually with TikZ or something.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,draft]{scrbook}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
paperwidth=11.7in,
paperheight=8.27in,
top=1in,
bottom=1in,
outer=1.5in, 
inner=0.7in,
voffset=0in,
marginparwidth=0.5in,
marginparsep=0.2in,
footskip=0em,
headsep=0pt,
nofoot,
nohead  
}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\chapterfont[LetterSpace=-12]{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries\color{gray!100!white!50}\fontsize{\paperheight}{\paperheight}\selectfont}%
{\resizebox{!}{\paperheight+1in}{\chapterfont\thechapter}}%
{-\paperheight}%
{\color{black}\raggedright\Huge}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0in}{-1.5in}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{20}
\chapter{Twenty One}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Example with full overlap (value of `-35`):

[image]

Comment: But it is not what I want really. The idea is to make one number look like it is behind another, by darkening part that overlaps.

Comment: Ok I can delete it. I think what you want is a really tough problem.

Comment: yeah, that's why I asked it here)

Comment: No need to delete it, though. It might still be useful to someone.

Comment: for the overlapping effect, just add "Opacity=0.5" to the `\chapterfont` (only works with luatex), no need to treat the digits individually or even to let loose tikz...

Comment: @Robert That doesn't seem to work for me. I can change the overall opacity of the digits, but there is no overlapping effect. (TL 2017).

Comment: @AlanMunn That's strange. This is what I get with `\newfontfamily\chapterfont[LetterSpace=-35,Opacity=0.5]{Latin Modern Roman}`: [http://imgur.com/a/8anWE](http://imgur.com/a/8anWE) (TL 2016, though)

Comment: @Robert Very strange. It doesn't work for me with TL 2016 either.  What OS are you using? (I'm on a Mac) And checking with four different PDF viewers doesn't change things.

Comment: Also Mac here. I can see the overlapping transparency in Preview and Skim, but not in Acrobat...

Comment: @Robert Wow that's even stranger if you're using a Mac too. Those were the three I tested with too (the fourth being the TeXShop previewer.)

Comment: ... and I could add the TeXworks previewer, which also shows the effect. Ah well, no idea for now, very strange indeed ...

Answer (score 5):

This is not really an answer to the original question, just a note from a discussion with Steven. Here is a crude method of squeezing and coloring the overlap using tikz opacity. Stevens sqeeze slitter code is stil used.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{tikz,etoolbox,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\myList{}
\def\intens{50}
\def\adjustment{0pt}
\def\pullback{10mm}
\def\squeeze#1#2\relax{
  \listxadd\myList{{#1}{\intens}}
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else%
  \xdef\intens{\the\numexpr\intens+25\relax}%
  \squeeze#2\relax%
  \fi}
\newcommand\Handler[1]{
  \begingroup
  \def\Splitter##1##2\relax{\gdef\VAL{##1}\gdef\INT{##2}}
  \expandafter\Splitter#1\relax
  \node[gray!100!white!\INT,opacity=0.5] 
  at ($(0,0)+(\adjustment,0)$) {\fontsize{10cm}{10cm}\selectfont\VAL};
  \global\dimdef\adjustment{\adjustment+\pullback}
  \endgroup
  }
\newcommand\DoSqeezed[1]{%
  \def\myList{}%
  \dimdef\adjustment{0pt}%
  \edef\tmp{#1}%
  \expandafter\squeeze\tmp\relax%
  \tikz\forlistloop\Handler\myList;
}
\begin{document}
\DoSqeezed{21}
\DoSqeezed{213}
\end{document}
```

This could probably be placed in the background either through some feature in `titlesec` (I don;t use it so unfamilliar) or by using a standard

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

instead of the `\tikz ... ;` wrapper.

[image]

---

Slightly adjusted version, which should also work with old style numerals. Also switched to `memoir` to test a few things that are not easy to test in the `standalone` class

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1cm}*1
\checkandfixthelayout
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{tikz,etoolbox,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\myList{}
\newcommand\intens{50}
\newcommand\adjustment{0pt}
\newcommand\pullback{10mm}
\def\squeeze#1#2\relax{
  \listxadd\myList{{#1}{\intens}}
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else%
  \xdef\intens{\the\numexpr\intens+25\relax}%
  \squeeze#2\relax%
  \fi}
\newcommand\Handler[1]{
  \begingroup
  \def\Splitter##1##2\relax{\gdef\VAL{##1}\gdef\INT{##2}}
  \expandafter\Splitter#1\relax
  \node[anchor=mid west,gray!100!white!\INT,opacity=0.5] 
  at ($(0,0)+(\adjustment,0)$) {\fontsize{10cm}{10cm}\selectfont\VAL};
  \global\dimdef\adjustment{\adjustment+\pullback}
  \endgroup
  }
\newcommand\DoSqeezed[1]{%
  \renewcommand\myList{}%
  \dimdef\adjustment{0pt}%
  \edef\myTemp{#1}%
  \expandafter\squeeze\myTemp\relax%
  \tikz
  %[remember picture,overlay]
  \forlistloop\Handler\myList;
}
\begin{document}
%\newcounter{chapter}
\setcounter{chapter}{678}
\DoSqeezed{\thechapter}
\DoSqeezed{213}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, this is what I wanted from the beginning. I guess working this out will give a mignificent result.

Comment: Would be safer to avoid `\def` and I believe that `fix-cm` is no longer needed. (+1) for the core code, though.

Comment: @cfr on my TL16 frozen `fix-cm` is needed in order to scale the fonts that high. For some of the code the defs can be replaced but for the delimited stuff we probably cannot.

Comment: I'm obviously wrong about `fix-cm`, then. I must be confusing it with something else.

Answer (score 3):

You can use PDF primitive commands for overlapping. Especially the `/Multiply` method in Graphic State in order to create the overlapped area darker. You don't need to use Tikz.

```
 \def\thechapnum{12}

\pdfpageresources{/ExtGState << /mul << /Type /ExtGState /BM /Multiply >> >>}

\def\insertkerns#1{\ifx\end#1\else #1\kern-.3em \expandafter\insertkerns\fi}

\leavevmode{\bf\pdfsave\pdfliteral{/mul gs 0.5 g 80 0 0 80 -100 -500 cm}%
   \rlap{\expandafter\insertkerns\thechapnum\end}\pdfrestore}

rryuir weeeyuirw fuow ediwe yiriw rfirer rf re ipr ire 
rryuir weeeyuirw fuow ediwe yiriw rfirer rf re ipr ire 
rryuir weeeyuirw fuow ediwe yiriw rfirer rf re ipr ire 
rryuir weeeyuirw fuow ediwe yiriw rfirer rf re ipr ire 
rryuir weeeyuirw fuow ediwe yiriw rfirer rf re ipr ire 
rryuir weeeyuirw fuow ediwe yiriw rfirer rf re ipr ire 
rryuir weeeyuirw fuow ediwe yiriw rfirer rf re ipr ire 
rryuir weeeyuirw fuow ediwe yiriw rfirer rf re ipr ire 
rryuir weeeyuirw fuow ediwe yiriw rfirer rf re ipr ire 

\bye
```

Note that the parameters of `cm` operator are used for scaling and shifting the result into proper place in the page.

[image: overlapping]